# Ajax post returning data to address bar

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

So I'm having an issue with ajax POST where it is returning the data to the address bar as if it's doing a get request but I've only every specified to do a POST. The funny thing is, this code was working when I pushed it to my git repo. I noticed the issue when I was testing a new commit, so I then reverted to this commit and the issue is appearing when before, it was not.

example return- http://localhost:50922/Agency?id=0&createdbytype=&lastupdatedbytype=&created=01%2F01%2F0001+00%3A00%3A00&lastupdated=01%2F01%2F0001+00%3A00%3A00&name=100test&address1=test&address2=test&address3=test&town=test&countyid=1&postcode=test&telephoneno=54252636&

My submit javascript function

```
function SubmitForm(form) {
        if ($(form).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: form.action,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        Popup.dialog('close');
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();

                        $.notify(data.message,
                            {
                                globalPosition: "bottom center",
                                className: "success"
                            });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My form designator

```
<form>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "Agency", FormMethod.Post, new {onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)"}))
```

On post the form should run that piece of JS above but it only ever does a get request and as I said previously, this code was working.

The POST should post the data to a method in my controller but it never gets that far now. I've tried debugging from the top of the submit JS and as soon as I open the page, the first thing the debugger gets to is here:

```
function Delete(id) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this item?")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Agency")/'+id, //<- here
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();

                        $.notify(data.message,
                            {
                                globalPosition: "bottom center",
                                className: "success"
                            });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Specifically

```
url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Agency")/'+id,
```

The delete function however is working fine. It changes a boolean for the id passed as it is a soft delete where a tuple is marked as either deleted or not deleted.

I'm completely lost on why this issue is occuring. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `BeginForm()` inside a `<form>` element (nested forms are invalid html), and its the outer form (which by default is a GET) which is submitting,  not the inner form (and as a consequence your `SubmitForm()` script is never executed).

Remove the outer `<form>` form element.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just went back a few commits to see which didn't have the extra form tag and it works fine. Not sure why I added it. Again thanks a bunch :D